# Ruby Asana Gem - Get all tasks with particular tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, activeresource, asana

Im using the Ruby Asana gem https://github.com/rbright/asana.

As per the documentation, in my controller I have:

```
tag = Asana::Tag.find(6498432136675)
@waiting_tasks = tag.tasks
```

However, this returns:

```
Failed.  Response code = 400.  Response message = Bad Request.
```

I have confirmed that the id is correct. If i use:

```
puts tag.inspect
```

I get the following:

```
#<Asana::Tag:0x007f94432af498 @attributes={"id"=>6498432136675, "created_at"=>"2013-07-14T10:05:13.070Z", "name"=>"Waiting for", "notes"=>"", "workspace"=>#<Asana::Workspace:0x007f94432aea98 @attributes={"id"=>6399696678844, "name"=>"Ministry of Crazy Ideas"}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false>, "color"=>"light-teal", "followers"=>[]}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>
```

I dont understand why this is not returning the tasks as documented in the read me. If anyone can shed any light on this I would be hugely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's most likely a bug in the ruby gem. However, it could be an underlying API issue. Try `curl -u <YOUR API KEY>: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tags/6498432136675/tasks` - if that works, the gem isn't constructing the right URL (aka, that one). If it still returns a 400, the issue may be with the API.

Comment: Thanks.

The curl command returns the correct data with no 404, so Im guessing its a problem with the gem. Is there a way to see what url the gem is constructing?